Kibana logs in a spring boot API
I'm refactoring an api that logs absolutely everything to kibana and some code repeats in the logic of all my endpoints. There is something I can do that works as a exception or something like that to add to my methods that let me write less code?

public ResponseEntity<Object> saveAddress(..params...) throws ValidationException {

        //method body

        KibanaLog.logSuccess(null, String.valueOf(HttpStatus.OK), "PUT", "accessPoint",
                jsonInput, jsonOutput, new Date(), null);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Dirección actualizada correctamente", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

I'm moving all the controllers logic to particular services to clean controllers code and I just thought that maybe I could solve the kibana logs by doing something like that
